# UDF For Finding Elements in a table

Tags: python

I need to create a User Defined Function that will accept an OwnerID as an input, and output a vector with the associated PetID(s).

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    pets = pd.read_csv('pets (1).csv')
    def OwnerFunc (OwnerID):
        print ("OwnerID: ", OwnerID)
        return;
    OwnerFunc(OwnerID=pets["PetID"])
```

The pets df has columns for PetID, Name, Kind, Age, and OwnerID.

I have it to where it will return all PetIDs, but not any specifically associated. I apolgize that I am still very new to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep function names lowercase like `def foo()`.

```
pets = pd.read_csv('pets (1).csv')
def owner_func (OwnerID):
    print ("OwnerID: ", OwnerID)
    return pets["PetID"][pets["OwnerID"]==OwnerID]
```

I assume you're looking to return the pet name associated with the owner name. If that's not the case let me know.

Comment: Chained indexing is bad. Prefer `pets.loc[pets['OwnerID'] == OwnerID, 'PetID']`.

Comment: See [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy).

Comment: While I agree that grabbing a view is necessary for assigning values to a series, there are different reasons for creating a copy vs creating a view. In this case it probably doesn't matter

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! What do you suggest is the best way to test this function out?